# Using next button on PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a pageViewcontroller and it works well, I can scroll left and right but now I want to be able to add button and use button to next to the next page instead of swiping on the Viewcontroller.

below is my basic code for swipping left to right

```
extension BaseVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! TableVC).pageIndex

        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1

        return viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index = (viewController as! TableVC).pageIndex

        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1

        if (index == self.pg.count) {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
    }


    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pg.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.currentIndex
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TableVC? {
        if self.pg.count == 0 || index >= self.pg.count {
            return nil
        }

        let pageContentViewController = TableVC()
        pageContentViewController.pageM = pg
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        currentIndex = index
        pageContentViewController.tableView.reloadData()

        return pageContentViewController
    }
}
```

the nextBtn and backBtn func is as follow

```
@objc nextBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    @objc backBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    }
```

any help would be appriitated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this inside a `UIPageViewController` subclass

```
self.setViewControllers([someVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I do not understand your solution, I am trying use a Button action to change it

Comment: to manually navigate you need to set the vc you need to navigate to `someVC` according to your UI to get the next and previous vcs use the same code inside the before and after data source methods

Comment: where are those actions inside ?

Comment: added to targets of UIButton

Comment: where is the button inside the pager itself or it's child vcs ?

Comment: copy paste the above line of code and init someVC with any vc and try it inside the actions ,  you need to have an index variable to keep track of current vc inside the array of vcs